# NHibernate QueryOver to sort each of the one-to-many collections

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, queryover

Consider this contrived domain:

```
namespace TryHibernate.Example {

public class Computer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Maker Maker { get; set; }
}

public class Maker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

} // namespace
```

If I just query all computers, their devices will be randomly ordered. I'd like to have them ordered by the maker's name. I can't really do it with `HasMany().OrderBy()` because as far as I can tell `OrderBy` can only use local columns (so I can sort it by `Device.Id`, for example). Moreover, it would be nice to control ordering on a per-query basis, so I'm looking for a `QueryOver` solution.

The farthest I could get to was this:

```
using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("temp.sqlite").ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Computer>(new ExampleConfig())
            .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Never())
            .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())))
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).Create(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory())
{
    using (ISession db = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        Computer comp = new Computer();
        comp.Devices = new List<Device>();
        Device dev1 = new Device();
        comp.Devices.Add(dev1);
        dev1.Maker = new Maker() { Name = "IBM"};
        Device dev2 = new Device();
        comp.Devices.Add(dev2);
        dev2.Maker = new Maker() { Name = "Acer"};
        db.Persist(comp);
        db.Flush();
    }
    using (ISession db = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {   // This is the part I'm having trouble with:
        Device devAlias = null;
        Maker makerAlias = null;
        IList<Computer> comps = db.QueryOver<Computer>()
            .JoinAlias(c => c.Devices, () => devAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => devAlias.Maker, () => makerAlias)
            .OrderBy(() => makerAlias.Name).Asc
            .List();
        Console.WriteLine(comps.Count);
        foreach (Device dev in comps[0].Devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dev.Maker.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But of course it doesn't do what I want. It tries to sort the whole list by the maker's name. It succeeds, too, as I can see from the SQL, and I actually get a useless Cartesian product of computers with devices sorted by the device maker.

But then it issues another SQL query to fetch the devices, this time without sorting. I guess NHibernate has no idea that my joins were meant to fetch the children.

The question is, how can I control that second query? For example, to order devices by the maker's name, or to get each `Computer.Devices` list to contain only devices made by, say, IBM (if any). I guess I need a subquery for that, but where do I plug it in?

Just for completeness, here is my config:

```
class ExampleConfig : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.Namespace == "TryHibernate.Example";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for a while with Bozhidar's answer, I got it somewhat working. I had to do a manual mapping for the *Computer,* like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="all" default-lazy="false">
  <class name="TryHibernate.Example.Computer, TryHibernate" table="Computer">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib" column="Id" generator="identity" />
    <bag name="Devices">
      <key column="ComputerId" />
      <one-to-many class="TryHibernate.Example.Device, TryHibernate" />
      <loader query-ref="DeviceLoader" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <sql-query name="DeviceLoader">
    <load-collection alias="Device" role="TryHibernate.Example.Computer.Devices" />
    SELECT Device.Id, Device.Maker_Id, Device.ComputerId, Maker.Name
    FROM Device JOIN Maker ON (Maker.Id = Device.Maker_Id)
    WHERE Device.ComputerId=?
    ORDER BY Maker.Name
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This goes into an embedded resource named *Computer.hbm.xml.* Then the code works just like this:

```
using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("temp.sqlite").ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Employee>(new ExampleConfig())
            .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Never())
            .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())))
    .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).Create(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory())
{
    using (ISession db = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        Computer comp = new Computer();
        comp.Devices = new List<Device>();
        Device dev1 = new Device();
        comp.Devices.Add(dev1);
        dev1.Maker = new Maker() { Name = "IBM" };
        Device dev2 = new Device();
        comp.Devices.Add(dev2);
        dev2.Maker = new Maker() { Name = "Acer" };
        db.Transaction.Begin();
        db.Persist(comp);
        db.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    using (ISession db = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        IList<Computer> comps = db.QueryOver<Computer>().List();
        Console.WriteLine(comps.Count);
        foreach (Device dev in comps[0].Devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dev.Maker.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can't say I'm happy with this. First, it seems to be too much work to just order something, which SQL supports out-of-the box. And it can't be customized at query level, which kind of defeats the purpose of my question. Then, the *bag* tag makes me feel rather uneasy. It means an *unordered* collection. Sure, it *seems* to preserve the order, but are there any guarantees? And stupid NHibernate just doesn't allow to use *list* there because, you see, it won't be a “true” mapping. You'll need a silly “index” column to get a true list!

All this just to sort something trivial. Makes me think why things like [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) come to life. .Net needs something like that (nOOQ anyone?), desperately. Just use typesafe embedded SQL with a code generator and automatic conversion to/from POCOs.

Comment: "it seems to be too much work to just order something, which SQL supports out-of-the box" - totally agree. It should be simpler but it isn't. NHibernate often has this ability to be both mature and ... stupid at the same time; not to mention the documentation quality... However there is LINQ support in NH. Have you seen that?

Comment: @Bozhidar, right, I've seen Linq, but I'm not sure if it can be used in this case, and I'm not sure whether it maps to SQL or does in-memory ordering, which is kind of pointless since I can always just do that myself on the fetched collection.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by interfering the SQL select statement for `Device`es retrieval. The most elegant solution to me is using custom loader. But this is
[not supported through Fluent NHibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Current-NHibernate-Features-Not-Supported-In-Fluent). Fortunately you can write single hbm.xml somewhere in your project and add it through fluent like so:

Device.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
    <class name="TryHibernate.Example.Device, TryHibernate" table="Device">
        <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib" column="Id" generator="identity" />
        <property name="Name" />
        <many-to-one name="Maker" column="MakerId" />
        <many-to-one name="Computer" column="ComputerId" />
        <loader query-ref="DeviceLoader" />
    </class>

    <sql-query name="DeviceLoader">
        <return alias="dev" class="TryHibernate.Example.Device, TryHibernate" lock-mode="read">
            <return-property name="Computer" column="ComputerId" />
            <return-property name="Maker" column="MakerId" />
        </return>

        SELECT Device.Id AS {dev.Id}, Device.Name As {dev.Name}, Device.MakerId AS {dev.MakerId}, Device.ComputerId AS {dev.ComputerId}
        FROM Device INNER JOIN Maker ON Maker.Id = Device.MakerId
        WHERE Device.Id=?
        ORDER BY Device.ComputerId, Maker.Name
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then while building the session factory do:

```
    using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("temp.sqlite").ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
            AutoMap.AssemblyOf(new ExampleConfig())
                .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Never())
                .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())))
        .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
        .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).Create(true, true))
        .BuildSessionFactory())
```

---

Another thought that hit me is you could specify `Subselect()` for your mapping; like this:

```
public class DeviceMap : ClassMap<Device>
{
    public DeviceMap()
    {
        Table("Device");
        Subselect(@"
  SELECT TOP 100 Device.Id , Device.Name, Device.MakerId , Device.ComputerId
  FROM Device INNER JOIN Maker ON Maker.Id = Device.MakerId
  ORDER BY Device.ComputerId, Maker.Name
");

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        References(x => x.Computer).Column("ComputerId");
        References(x => x.Maker).Column("MakerId");
    }
```

As you notice I used the `TOP` clause. It is necessary because the sub-select statement becomes a subquery and as you might know

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

---

Yet another though is to implement an `IInterceptor` interface and alter the SQL as appropriate. Like so:

```
public class SqlStatementInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var result = sql;

        if (sql.IndexOfCaseInsensitive("FROM Device") != -1)
        {
            var sqlText = string.Format("WITH cteDev AS ({0}{1}{0}){0}SELECT cteDev.* FROM cteDev INNER JOIN Maker ON cteDev.MakerId1_0_ = Maker.Id ORDER BY Maker.Name", Environment.NewLine, sql.ToString());

            result = sql
                .Insert(0, "WITH cteDev AS (")
                .Append(")SELECT cteDev.* FROM cteDev INNER JOIN Maker ON cteDev.MakerId1_0_ = Maker.Id ORDER BY Maker.Name");
            ;

        }

        Trace.WriteLine(result.ToString());

        return result;
    }
}
```

*** With this one you need to use conventions and figure how NHibernate generates the name of the tables and columns.

Comment: Wow, that was... unexpected. Less than a day from the bounty expiration, I thought that it is going to just disappear. I've only tried your first solution, since others seem to be even more complicated, not giving anything in exchange. The first one didn't quite work, and it doesn't give me the ability to control ordering on a per-query basis, but it still pointed me into a direction that allowed me to get it at least somehow working. See my answer for details. If there are no better answers, you'll get the bounty for sure!

Comment: Give a try to the second option - the `Subselect(string)`. The only trade off is the `TOP` clause which don't seem to be showstopper - I believe you could figure out sufficient for your situation number of records... Plus it isn't too hard to implement; it was the fastest approach for me.

Comment: If I do a `Subselect`, it keeps on trying to do absolutely ridiculous `INSERT INTO (SELECT ...)` when trying to add devices. It's almost as if it just replaces the table name with my subselect wherever it feels like it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really supported by NHibernate. There are plenty of features you can combine and probably get close to it. These solutions tend to break quickly and are hard to maintain.

**QueryOver**: You can tell NHibernate to join children and fill it into a collection at the same time.

```
db.QueryOver<Computer>()
    .JoinAlias(c => c.Devices, () => devAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => devAlias.Maker, () => makerAlias)
    .Fetch(x => x.Devices).Eager
    .OrderBy(() => makerAlias.Name).Asc
    .List();
```

This works somewhat well with one collection, because of the Cartesian product problem. Your case is probably already too complex.

**Mapping**: Another solution is ordering in the mapping file. You probably manage it to order by the name of the maker when you add some SQL into a "formula". I wouldn't do it. It destroys the performance of the application, because it needs all these joining and ordering just to get these things out of the database.

**Sort on writing**: You should consider to put it in correct order to the database. Map it as List, not Bag. To be honest: devices ordered by maker sounds more like a displaying thing than a data management thing and should therefore be done when reading. It would also be hard to keep in correct order when e.g. a maker changes the name. However, I wanted to have this option added for completeness, often this makes sense.

**KISS**: Now to the simplest solution you can possibly get.

-drum roll-

Order it in memory using Linq.

```
foreach(var computer in computers)
{
  foreach(var device in computer.Devices.OrderBy(x => x.Maker.Name))
  {

  }
}
```

Done.

Comment: The `Fetch` way doesn't work for me: it still doesn't order collections owned by the computers in the resulting list.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: May be it doesn't even work. When it is a list and not a bag for instance, it is not even allowed to change the order. As I said: it's easy to break.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest giving yourself an hour. With that hour, write some entity framework processing for this specific query. I have converted NHibernate to Entity framework and most likely you are having a random xml linking between the tables in question. Within entity framework these 'navigation'/'virtual collections' are implemented explicitly within the ORM.

If you cannot navigate to your object within NHibernate I suggest you add a small slice of Entity Framework to a separate Class Library to get acquainted with the ORM that will explain why your possible many to many relationship will not work. If you have a one to many relationship, this should be as easy as this.that.

Comment: The whole point of this example is to learn NHibernate, so EF obviously won't help me here. And you've missed another point—it's Fluent NHibernate, so no XML, no silly attributes, almost no manual mapping in code. The code presented in the question actually does all the mapping. Can EF even do that?

Comment: EF can and does map things for you. It even creates a 1 to many to your many to many by creating another navigation property. I had to migrate an entire NHibernate setup to Entity framework and the pain point I still remember was implicit joins of NH.

Comment: I don't like how EF dependencies creep into domain. Reminds me of JPA. I don't like that. But then again, I don't like ORMs. And JPA is not that bad, so maybe I'll give EF a try.

Comment: EF will only creep into domain if you let it. I abstract interfaces to wrap my POCO objects so my architecture does not affect my application. Best of luck!! ps. try this, https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/documentation